# function pointer with template argument inside a structure

Tags: c++, templates, structure, function-pointers

```
enum VasaType { BASE = 0, PERENTITY = 1, ASYNC = 2, VECTORED = 4};

 
template <typename T>
using func = void(*)(T);
template <typename T>
void callv(T request) {
    //reqEntities.push_back(request->srcVVolId);
}
template <typename T>
void callc(T request) {
    //reqEntities.push_back(request->eid);
}
struct VASAApiInfo {
   VasaType type : 3;
   template <typename T>
   func<T> fn(T request);
  //void (*fn)(T);
};

static std::vector<struct VASAApiInfo> apiInfoVec = {
  
   {(VasaType)(VasaType::PERENTITY | VasaType::ASYNC), callc}, // createVirtualVolume
   {VasaType::PERENTITY, callv}                           // deleteVirtualVolume
  
};
```

I am getting the following compilation error :

```
prog.cpp:221:1: error: could not convert ‘{{((VasaType)(1 | 2)), callc}, {PERENTITY, callv}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::vector<VASAApiInfo>’
 };
```

I need a way to have a function pointer which takes template argument inside a structure.

Comment: Function pointers are inherently runtime constructs. Templates are always instantiated at compile time. A function pointer must have a monomorphic type, so that it can be reified at runtime.

Comment: function template is not a single function. it's impossible that a function pointer points to a function template.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the function pointer inside your structure, the type of the function pointer has to be known at compile time. What you could do is make your struct a template like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct VASAApiInfo {
    VasaType type : 3;
    void (*fn)(T);
};
```

Note the syntax for a function pointer member.

Then it is possible to instantiate your struct template like this for example:

```
static std::vector<VASAApiInfo<int>> apiInfoVec = {

   {(VasaType)(VasaType::PERENTITY | VasaType::ASYNC), callc}, // createVirtualVolume
   {{VasaType::PERENTITY}, callv}                           // deleteVirtualVolume

};
```